# Understanding command line arguments in custom shell and the effect of using quote

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, c

I am creating a custom shell using C language and I am successful with parsing, fork and exec, pipes, redirection etc. I noticed one particular type of command which seems to be throwing my shell off.

In bash shell , the following command works.

```
bash> echo "abc" >> tempFile
bash> sed  s/a/b/g  tempFile
bash> sed  's/a/b/g'  tempFile
```

In my custom shell,

```
mysh> sed  s/a/b/g  tempFile
mysh> sed  's/a/b/g'  tempFile
```

The first sed command works, the second fails as

```
sed: 1: "'s/a/b/g'": invalid command code '
```

This is how I fork and execute the command in my shell.

`execvp(qualifiedPath, arguments)`

In both the above command the qualifiedPath is `"/usr/bin/sed"` and the arguments are `NULL` terminated array of character pointer like
`[0] =  "sed"`,
`[1] =  "s/a/b/g"`,
`[2] =  "TEMP"`,
`[3] =  (char*)NULL`
for the first command and
`[0] =  "sed"`,
`[1] =  "'s/a/b/g'"`,
`[2] =  "TEMP"`,
`[3] =  (char*)NULL` for the second command respectively.

Does anyone know why the single quote causes exec to fail, and also the same behavior is observed for

```
mysh> sed  "s/a/b/g"  tempFile
sed: 1: "'s/a/b/g'": invalid command code '
```

Comment: You're really close to the answer. Run these two commands in your shell and bash: `echo "test"; echo 'test'`. You'll find that your shell includes the single quotes, while in bash they're removed.

Comment: To extend on what @iFreilicht said above, `bash` consumes the quotes before it execs the process -- it doesn't include them in what it passes to the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @iFreilicht and @Andy Dalton. It was very silly of me. The Bash shell consumes the quotes and depending on if the argument was enclosed with ' or " , the shell will interpolate the arguments. This [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) offers a more detailed explanation.

Comment: There's a reason that bash specifies [Quote Removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal) as an explicit step in the expansions.